How can I only display a circle as legend symbol?
I've create a line chart with chart.js. I set symbol type circle but in the circle why also show line and circle symbol combined.
See below images you can get more idea
I want to only circle not line on the legend symbol how to do that?

In the above images link I want to only add circle or Sqare legend symbol but in above image you can see some line include in the symbol why its line I have no idea about that.
Highcharts.chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chartcontainer',
                type: chart_type,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                width: this.chartWidth,
                height: this.chartHeight,
                options3d: {
                    enabled: this.chart_settings.threed_chart_settings.enabled_threed,
                    alpha: this.chart_settings.threed_chart_settings.alpha_value,
                    axisLabelPosition: "auto",
                    beta: this.chart_settings.threed_chart_settings.beta_value,
                    depth: this.chart_settings.threed_chart_settings.depth_value,
                    viewDistance: 25
                },
                spacingTop: this.chart_settings.title_setting.show_title ? !this.emptyChartData ? 10 : 25 : 25
            },
            noData: {
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: '15px'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: this.chart_settings.title_setting.show_title ? !this.emptyChartData ? this.chart_settings.title_setting.title_name : ' ' : ' ',
                style: {
                    fontSize: this.chart_settings.title_setting.font_size + 'px',
                    color: this.chart_settings.title_setting.font_color,
                    fontWeight: this.chart_settings.title_setting.font_style.bold,
                    fontStyle: this.chart_settings.title_setting.font_style.italic,
                    textDecoration: this.chart_settings.title_setting.font_style.underline,
                    'font-family': this.chart_settings.title_setting.font_family + ', sans-serif'
                },
                align: this.chart_settings.title_setting.horizontal_align,
                verticalAlign: this.chart_settings.title_setting.vertical_align
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.show_legend,
                itemStyle: {
                    fontSize: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.font_size + 'px',
                    color: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.font_color,
                    fontWeight: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.font_style.bold,
                    fontStyle: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.font_style.italic,
                    textDecoration: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.font_style.underline,
                    'font-family': this.chart_settings.legend_setting.font_family + ', sans-serif'
                },
                align: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.horizontal_align,
                verticalAlign: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.vertical_align,
                alignColumns: false,
                navigation: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                symbolRadius: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.symbol_type == "square" ? 0 : 100,
                symbolHeight: 12,
                symbolWidth: 12
            },
            xAxis: {
                visible: this.chart_settings.X_AXIS_setting.show_label,
                gridLineColor: this.chart_settings.X_AXIS_setting.show_grid_lines ? '#e6e6e6' : 'transparent',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                categories: chart_data[chart_data.length - 1].label,
                crosshair: true,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontSize: this.chart_settings.X_AXIS_setting.font_size + 'px',
                        color: this.chart_settings.X_AXIS_setting.font_color,
                        fontWeight: this.chart_settings.X_AXIS_setting.font_style.bold,
                        fontStyle: this.chart_settings.X_AXIS_setting.font_style.italic,
                        textDecoration: this.chart_settings.X_AXIS_setting.font_style.underline,
                        'font-family': this.chart_settings.X_AXIS_setting.font_family + ', sans-serif'
                    },
                    format: x_axes_label.prefix + '{value}' + x_axes_label.suffix
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                visible: this.chart_settings.Y_AXIS_setting.show_label,
                gridLineColor: this.chart_settings.Y_AXIS_setting.show_grid_lines ? '#e6e6e6' : 'transparent',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                reversedStacks: false,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontSize: this.chart_settings.Y_AXIS_setting.font_size + 'px',
                        color: this.chart_settings.Y_AXIS_setting.font_color,
                        fontWeight: this.chart_settings.Y_AXIS_setting.font_style.bold,
                        fontStyle: this.chart_settings.Y_AXIS_setting.font_style.italic,
                        textDecoration: this.chart_settings.Y_AXIS_setting.font_style.underline,
                        'font-family': this.chart_settings.Y_AXIS_setting.font_family + ', sans-serif'
                    },
                    format: y_axes_label.prefix + '{value}' + y_axes_label.suffix
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    depth: 25
                },
                line: {
                    marker: {
                        symbol: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.symbol_type,
                    }
                },
                bar: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                area: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    marker: {
                        symbol: this.chart_settings.legend_setting.symbol_type
                    }
                },
                pie: {
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                    innerSize: isdoughnut ? doughnut_circle_size + '%' : '0%',
                    showInLegend: true,
                    dataLabels: {
                        format: this.chart_settings.pie_label_setting.format_value == 'value' ? this.chart_settings.label_setting.label_values.prefix + '{y}' + this.chart_settings.label_setting.label_values.suffix : '{point.percentage:.1f}%',
                        connectorWidth: this.chart_settings.pie_label_setting.connector_thick,
                        padding: 1
                    },
                    depth: this.chart_settings.threed_chart_settings.depth_value,
                    startAngle: this.select_chart_type == "semi-doughnut" ? -90 : undefined,
                    endAngle: this.select_chart_type == "semi-doughnut" ? 90 : undefined,
                    center: this.select_chart_type == "semi-doughnut" ? ['50%', '85%'] : [null, null],
                    size: this.select_chart_type == "semi-doughnut" ? '120%' : null
                },
                cylinder: {
                    colors: chart_data[chart_data.length - 1].color_array,
                    colorByPoint: true
                },
                series: {
                    animation: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: this.chart_settings.label_setting.show_label,
                        style: {
                            textShadow: false,
                            textOutline: 'none',
                            fontSize: this.chart_settings.label_setting.font_size + 'px',
                            color: this.chart_settings.label_setting.font_color,
                            fontWeight: this.chart_settings.label_setting.font_style.bold,
                            fontStyle: this.chart_settings.label_setting.font_style.italic,
                            textDecoration: this.chart_settings.label_setting.font_style.underline,
                            'font-family': this.chart_settings.label_setting.font_family + ', sans-serif'
                        },
                        format: this.chart_settings.label_setting.label_values.prefix + "{y}" + this.chart_settings.label_setting.label_values.suffix
                    }
                },
            },
            series: dataSeries
        });
   


Now you can check i have edit

You need to change the legendSymbol option which is set to lineMarker by default.
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      legendSymbol: 'rectangle'
    }
  }


Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0wejh5om/
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.legendSymbol
